# Le préfixe "re-" dans "représentation"

Tags: préfixes

Si on consulte [cette liste](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/prefixes.php), on apprend que le préfixe "re-" signifie "répétition, inversion, achèvement". Mais son usage dans le mot "représenter" ne me semble pas pouvoir être classifié dans une de ces cases.

[Ailleurs](http://www.hommes-et-faits.com/Linguistique/Jh_PrefixeRe.htm), on peut lire :

> Prenons le verbe : représenter. C’est précisément dans l’absence et non dans la présence que l’on représente, autrement dit, on essaie de rendre présent ce qui ne l’est pas, en dépit, au mépris de l’absence. Je me représente est d’ailleurs synonyme de je m’imagine, je suppose.

Je comprends ce qu'il écrit, mais je vois mal comment cela pourrait rentrer  ni dans le sens de répétition, ni d'inversion, ni d'achèvement.

Pourquoi le mot "représenter" (représentation, etc.) porte-t-il le préfixe "re" ? Est-ce une instance d'une utilisation plus générale de ce préfixe qui n'a pas été mentionnée dans la liste citée au début ?

Comment: Une liste plus complète: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/re-. Note que “rendre” est l'un des sens qui apparait dans cette liste.

Comment: La liste constitue une sur-simplification ; voir aussi sur TLFi l'article [re-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/re-) et celui sur le [verbe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/repr%C3%A9senter). Merci !

Answer (score 3):

Représenter peut signifier:

- « présenter à nouveau », donc avec un sens de répétition:

  > Je me représente au guichet. (je me présente à nouveau au guichet)
  >
  > Cette occasion se représentera peut-être
- s'imaginer quelque chose. C'est alors une inversion: on rend présent quelque chose qui ne l'est pas.

  > Je me représente la météorite comme une pierre noire calcinée.

Answer (score 2):

Peut être pour la même raison que la reconnaissance précède la connaissance. On est à deux doigts de la métaphysique là